# Failing Rspec Test with MongoID , Custom Authentication, Password Digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, mongoid

i have completed the rails tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/, and trying to implement the [user model](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users), but in MongoDB, using MongoID.

I have the following code, which is almost exactly the same as the tutorial, yet it's failing on one of the test cases.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :password_digest, type: String

  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50}
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: email_regex },
                                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

and rspec tests:

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe User do
  before do
     @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") 
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

 describe 'without a name' do
    before { @user.name = "" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

 describe 'without an email' do
    before { @user.email = "" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
 end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end      
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end      
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

 describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

    describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

The failure on the spec is:

```
........F..........

Failures:

  1) User return value of authenticate method with valid password 
     Failure/Error: it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
       expected: #<User _id: 50e30a678bffa61a9e000001, _type: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$C6klW7B9ok4OIHFopy5AfuncvwNYTZqHWTbqpdd8gXmruSLlwizPO">
            got: #<User _id: 50e30f158bffa6df67000001, _type: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$mDCz9JVPXGSvpGBwbyHIsuV/k.lJ/ux1TuvgRzxSLYlIna/CdztN2"> (using ==)
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -#<User _id: 50e30a678bffa61a9e000001, _type: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$C6klW7B9ok4OIHFopy5AfuncvwNYTZqHWTbqpdd8gXmruSLlwizPO">
       +#<User _id: 50e30f158bffa6df67000001, _type: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$mDCz9JVPXGSvpGBwbyHIsuV/k.lJ/ux1TuvgRzxSLYlIna/CdztN2">
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:89:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.79 seconds
19 examples, 1 failure
```

Update:

Did a bit more diggig, and querying the test database it seems that the data is not being cleared before each test case.

Updat2:

I have managed to fix this by including the following in my Spec Helper:

```
  config.before :each do
    Mongoid.purge!
  end
```

But tests are noticeably slower now! any idea how to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is calling save, which recreates the `password_digest`

```
describe "return value of authenticate method" do
   #before { @user.save }  #comment this line
   #....
end
```

Comment: Not really sure that is the problem, if i comment out the line, then all the tests related to return value of the authenticate actually fail. Since it cant find the document.